# Is it really a good technique to work with legacy code (with reinterpret_cast)?

Tags: c++

Below code came from a post about C++ interview questions [here](https://www.toptal.com/c-plus-plus/interview-questions). I've never known this technique :) (though it's claimed a good one :)). My questions are: In which situation do we need to use it? Do you often see it in your real production/legacy code?

**Question:**

> Implement a method to get topSecretValue for any given Something* object. The method should be cross-platform compatible and not depend on sizeof (int, bool, string).

```
class Something {
    Something() {
        topSecretValue = 42;
    }
    bool somePublicBool;
    int somePublicInt;
    std::string somePublicString;
private:
    int topSecretValue;
};
```

**Answer:**

> Create another class which has all the members of Something in the same order, but has additional public method which returns the value. Your replica Something class should look like:

```
class SomethingReplica {
public:
    int getTopSecretValue() { return topSecretValue; } // <-- new member function
    bool somePublicBool;
    int somePublicInt;
    std::string somePublicString;
private:
    int topSecretValue;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Something a;
    SomethingReplica* b = reinterpret_cast<SomethingReplica*>(&a);
    std::cout << b->getTopSecretValue();
}
```

> It’s important to avoid code like this in a final product, but it’s nevertheless a good technique when dealing with legacy code, as it can be used to extract intermediate calculation values from a library class. (Note: If it turns out that the alignment of the external library is mismatched to your code, you can resolve this using #pragma pack.)

Comment: You might want to study the *visitor* and *observer* patterns.

Comment: Pedantically, it is UB as aliasing rule is broken. but might work in practice.

Comment: As hack, adding friend or public method would do the job too. (as it should not go in production, it is only for temporary testing).

Comment: @eerorika where is to strict aliasing question? (it seems rustyx removed his comment).

Comment: See [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and [\[basic.lval\]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.lval#10). @eerorika btw not sure about the standard-layout exception.

Comment: This code is UB. It violates the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).
There are safer methods to "hack" a private member.
This approach should never be used at any level of code.

Comment: Goes to show that not all "C++ interview questions" are created equal. On second thought, they're all abysmal.

Comment: @rustyx you appear to be right. I must have mixed strict aliasing with some other case. I think layout-compatibility would have made union punning OK (if the classes were layout-compatible).

Comment: @PasserBy disagree. My C++ interview questions are superb! :)

Comment: I always solve this problem with a very simple code: `#define class struct #define private public` ;)

Comment: @SergeyA: But then, you might break layout (as you no longer mix private/public section, disallowing some potential reorganization), name mangling might also be impacted. (you also break ODR).

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, this is very undefined behaviorish. I only used it once in production code, because of some too-stupid-to-explain policies, but it got the job done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this without `reinterpret_cast`.  There is a trick using templates and friends that is outlined in the following blog post that demonstrates the technique:

[Access to private members. That's easy!](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html)

This is certainly safer than the interviewer's approach, since it eliminates human error in re-creating the class definition.  Is this approach good at all, though?  The given question has some incredibly artificial constraints that would rarely apply to a 'real' project.  If it's a C++ project and you have access to the header file, why not just add a getter?  If it's not a C++ project, why are you so constrained in your definition of the interop class?

Comment: There also is libraries that exist just for that. I'm particularly impressed with their macro less solution: https://github.com/hliberacki/cpp-member-accessor

Comment: Why not modify header file? The interviewer might say he wants to test your knowledge about layout compatibility :)

Comment: Offtopic: @GuillaumeRacicot good to know someone use it ;) or maybe it's not that good :D considering character of that lib.