# Access control in template parameters

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54907320/4832499), which claims to subvert the access control system, I wrote the following minimal version of the hack

```
template<typename T>
inline T memptr{};

template<auto Val>
struct setptr
{
    struct setter { setter() { memptr<decltype(Val)> = Val; } };
    static setter s;
};

template<auto Val>
typename setptr<Val>::setter setptr<Val>::s{};
```

which is then [used as](https://godbolt.org/z/Tzaz1M)

```
class S
{
    int i;
};

template struct setptr<&S::i>;

auto no_privacy(S& s)
{
    return s.*memptr<int S::*>;
}
```

Why doesn't `template struct setptr<&S::i>;` violate access control?

Is it because [[class.access]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.access#4)

> Access control is applied uniformly to all names, whether the names are referred to from **declarations or expressions**.

specifically doesn't include instantiations? In which case, why doesn't it include instantiations?

<sub>**Errata**: Explicit instantiations are also classified as declarations.</sub>

Comment: See also http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm

Comment: We actually use this "hack" in *one* place in our code base to be able to call a private member function in a library that we *really need to* call ;-) But, I suspect it could also be useful in test frameworks where you may want to test protected and private members without having to inject friends and other stuff.

Comment: If you follow a few links from the answer, you get to [this](https://gist.github.com/dabrahams/1528856) commented version, where it is elaborated that explicit instantiations are the only place where you can form member function/field pointers while ignoring access. There is even more explanation in [this](https://github.com/hliberacki/cpp-member-accessor) library linked in the comments to an answer in the question you linked.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I actually saw those, but couldn't find the source of their claims.

Comment: We used to use this to workaround buggy `std::fstream` implementation in older visual studio version by accessing the underlying `FILE` handle

Comment: @Jarod42 [Huh?](https://godbolt.org/z/dr8bH9) Do inline variables have to be initialized?

Comment: @PasserBy: [Clang link error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/663fc44a027de678) and [No errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4e55a9aa5d33392).

Comment: @Jarod42 Seems like a bug to me. [basic.def]/2 specifies declarations are also definitions unless its one of the items in the list, of which there isn't inline variable declarations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [[temp.spec]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#6) (emphasis mine):

> **The usual access checking rules do not apply to names in a declaration of an explicit instantiation or explicit specialization**, with the exception of names appearing in a function body, default argument, base-clause, member-specification, enumerator-list, or static data member or variable template initializer.
>   [ Note: In particular, the template arguments and names used in the function declarator (including parameter types, return types and exception specifications) may be private types or objects that would normally not be accessible.
>   — end note
>    ]

So this technique you see abuses this rule, which is primarely there to allow implementers of a class specialize templates (such as traits) with private types or other private entities